# Native page rendering error with WL.NativePage.Show procedure using

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I created a hybrid application that open a native page. If the `UIViewController` which assigned to the opened page is objective-c type, then the page is well open. However, when Swift-type of the `UIViewController`, the Xcode throw the following error:

> WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  *** setObjectForKey: object
>   cannot be nil (key: SwiftTestPage)

What can cause this error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `WL.Nativpage.show` does not support Swift, using it like that may have unforseen consequences, like the one you are experiecing now.

Instead of `WL.Nativepage.show`, you should use the Action Sender API to call up any class ("page") you want, without the restrictions placed by `WL.Nativepage`. See here: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html